# Change ApplicationName in EntityFrameWorkCore-enabled applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, sql-server-profiler

If a software application uses Entity Framework Core (3.1) and connects to Microsoft SQL Server (2019) for data, in the SQL Server Profiler, we see it is listed as "**Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider**" under column "**ApplicationName**".

[image]

I wonder if we can change this name *in the application source code*? For example, to an easier-to-distinguish name, such as "FileServer".

The benefit is that when there are multiple *different* applications accessing that SQL Server, we can distinguish (or filter) them more easily.

Comment: The application name  passed to SQL Server is defined in the connection string in the application, using the `Application Name` property. You'll need to edit the connection string to add the property and define the value you want.

Comment: @Larnu, add that as an answer.